# SQL to Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

Does anybody know how to convert this on outerjoin on LINQ Lambda?

I wan to achieve this using lambda linq

```
SELECT * FROM Posts as A LEFT JOIN Reactions as B on A.Id = B.PostId AND @userId = b.userid
```

Here is my current linq code

```
 return await _dbContext.Posts
           .GroupJoin(_dbContext.Reactions,
           post => post.Id, reaction => reaction.PostId,
           (post, reactions) => new { post, reactions })
           .SelectMany(x => x.reactions.DefaultIfEmpty(),
           (post, reaction) => new { post.post, reaction })
```

Comment: what is `@userId` ? is it `a.userid`?

Comment: What's the issue that you have with your current LINQ code?

Comment: @NagibMahfuz on my c# code userId refers to method parameter GetPostsAsync(int page, string userId).

Comment: @Enigmativity I want to do an outer join using the postId and UserId(which is from the method parameter). Hope this make sense. Hard to explain as english is not my mother tounge.

Comment: @shanzap404 check my answer. Note: I have not tested it, but it should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to accomplish can be done in two different ways in SQL, and those ways can be translated to Linq.

Depending on your scenario (volume of data, indexes, etc) you may want to need one or another

### Option A: Join the filtered data

```
SELECT a.Name, b.* 
FROM 
    tableA 
    LEFT JOIN tableB on 
        b.Action='delete' AND a.Id = b.Id
```

would be translated in LINQ to something similar to:

```
var query =
    from a in db.TableA
    join pet in db.TableB.Where(x => x.Action=="delete") on a equals b.TableA into gj
    from leftJoined in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

and using method syntax:

```
var query = tableA
    .GroupJoin(
        tableB.Where(x => x.Action == "delete"),
        tableA => tableA, 
        tableB => tableB.tableA,
        (tableA, tableBs) => new {tableA, tableBs}
    ).SelectMany(x => x.tableBs.DefaultIfEmpty())
```

### Option B: Do the join and later filter the data

```
SELECT a.Name, b.* 
FROM 
    tableA 
    LEFT JOIN tableB on a.Id = b.Id 
WHERE 
    b.Id = NULL OR b.Action='delete'
```

would be translated to:

```
var query =
    from a in db.TableA
    join pet in db.TableB on a equals b.TableA into gj
    from leftJoined in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where lefjoined == null || leftjoined.Action == "delete"
```

Comment: While option B does return the same result as my query. Would you mind converting the Option A into a method syntax? I think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: @shanzap404, what is the point to use method syntax? It is less readable and maintainable especially with Joins.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I mainly use method syntax. But I agree with you that this is less readable.

Comment: I've managed now to reproduce the option A on method syntax. And upon looking at the generated query on SQL server profile it does not produce the same SQL query that I've mentioned in the question but it does return the result that I want. Though I honestly don't know if it is possible to reproduce the same syntax using LINQ query and method syntax,

Comment: @shanzap404 Feel free to edit my answer and add the method syntax to option A. And also to mark the asnwer as useful if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

A **left outer join** is a join in which each element of the first collection is returned, regardless of whether it has any correlated elements in the second collection. You can use LINQ to perform a left outer join by calling the `DefaultIfEmpty` method on the results of a group join.

You can use this approach

Query Syntax:

```
var query = (from post in Posts
            join reaction in Reactions
            on post.Id equals reaction.PostId
            into reaction
            from reaction in reaction.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                post.Id,
                //prod.Foo1,
                //post.Foo2,
                //reaction.Foo3,
                //reaction.Foo4,
                //you can select other fields too
            }).OrderBy(ps => ps.Id);
```

For more information visit [Perform left outer joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins#:%7E:text=A%20left%20outer%20join%20is,results%20of%20a%20group%20join.)

Comment: The OP is after an "outerjoin".

Comment: @Enigmativity outerjoin but filtered, gonna write a quick answer

Comment: You are missing the `AND @userId = b.userid` in the `LEFT JOIN` in OP's question. That makes the answer a bit more tricky

Comment: @Moshi Thanks for answering but yeah there are missing conditions as Cleptus mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't.  Flattening out related data like that is simply not necessary in LINQ.  Just fetch the data with its natural shape:

```
_dbContext.Posts.Include(p => p.Reactions)
```

This returns the Posts and any reactions, without having to repeat the Post data for each Reaction, or having nulls for Posts without Reactions.